# How to visualize this setup for deriving $\frac {dM}{dt}$ while water is evaporating

Tags: mathematics

> Establish a minuscule area dA on the interface and establish two angular coordinates. We measure the polar angle θ with respect to a line drawn perpendicular to dA and the azimuthal angle φ with respect to an arbitrary circle lying parallel to dA. Consider only those vapor molecules that float arbitrarily close to the interface and that have velocities v with speeds in the range between v and v+dv oriented in directions whose angular coordinates lie between θ and θ+dθ and between φ and φ+dφ.

This is an excerpt from the derivation of Langmuir's Equation. The full proof is given in this link http://bado-shanai.net/Map%20of%20Physics/mopLangmuirEvaporation.htm

I am having trouble in imagining this setup visually. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I can get from the first two sentences:

[image]

z-axis is the line perpendicular to dA.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even we came to the same conclusion. The vector points to a vapor molecule, right?

Comment: It seems, but I'm not sure what the third sentence means by "oriented in directions whose angular coordinates lie between θ and θ+dθ and between φ and φ+dφ", if the direction means directions of velocity or the position of molecule.

Comment: I think it means the direction of the velocity. If we assume that to be true then a change of velocity from $v$ to $v+dv$ leads to a respective change in $\theta$ and $\phi$ to $\theta+d\theta$ and $\phi+d\phi$